# Run cron jobs in intended python environment?

Tags: cron, python, users, environment-variables

- I have users `root` and `user1`
- All of my python scripts have been
  created by `user1`
- I have created a bash file that needs to be automated. The bash file calls my python scripts
- I have added my bash call to the cron file

However, my python environment for `root` is **not** the same as it is for `user1` (different versions, library packages, etc, etc). So when the cron kicks off, it gives me python errors like "library not found" because the `root` environment is being used.

How can I ensure that my cron commands run my python scripts under the `user1` python environment and not `root`?

Note that I've already tried using some variation of `su` in my cron file but it always asks for a password and I need this to be a fully automated process.

Comment: Use python virtual environments and then specify the full path to the python binary within the virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `sudo su`?

```
sudo su -l "user1" -c "/path/to/bashscript.sh"
```

Alternatively you could set the required environment at the top of your crontab:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
PATH=<user1 path>
LOGNAME=user1
USER=user1
HOME=/home/user1
```

And if necessary source your user1 config file(s) prior to executing your bash file:

```
0 12 * * * * . /home/user1/.bash_profile; /path/to/bashscript.sh
```

Comment: The very first line in your answer worked for me, exactly what I need to do. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using virtual environments, you can also activate the environment in cron:

```
0 12 * * * * . /%user1-venv-location%/bin/activate; /path/to/bashscript.sh
```