# ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: ubuntu, cron, python

The problem is that when the script is running through cron, for some reason the module is not found, but if you run it directly through Python, then everything is fine

Cron:

```
*/5 * * * * python /home/shhegolev/scripts/code5M_simple.py >> /home/shhegolev/scripts/logs.log 2>> /home/shhegolev/scripts/errors.log
```

`cat errors.log`
output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shhegolev/scripts/code5M_simple.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

but if i do it directly:

```
~/scripts$ python code5M_simple.py
```

or copy command from cron:

```
~/scripts$ python /home/shhegolev/scripts/code5M_simple.py >> /home/shhegolev/scripts/logs.log 2>> /home/shhegolev/scripts/errors.log
```

All fine!

`pip install numpy` says that:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/shhegolev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.21.5)
```

I can't figure out what's the problem

Code:

```
head -10 code5M_simple.py
import numpy
import talib
import csv
import time
from numpy import genfromtxt
import smtplib
import requests
from binance import Client
import random
import datetime
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458859/run-cron-jobs-in-intended-python-environment

Comment: Is this the crontab for `root` or your user? Did you install the modules globally, or only for your user? See the question mashuptwice linked for more possible environment issues.

Comment: Yes, I found a problem, I run cron as root, but the module was installed for the user, it's a shame for such a st*pid question (

Comment: We all make mistakes - but consider running it as your own user. You should only run stuff as `root` if it is strictly necessary.